# How to send selected parameter from dropdown to C# code behind file to use in place of User.Identity.Name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms

I was able to create a quick and dirty asp user website administration tool for a legacy application and I was able to implement tools for registration, activation, assign roles, create roles, but I am struggling to successfully create one that will allow you to select an existing user and delete all their related information from the underlying aspnet security database (Users, UserinRoles, Membership,etc..).

What I have done this far is developed a tool that queries my sql database and returns all the existing users and binds it to a dropdown list. I than have a delete button that calls a function in the code behind file that will delete all the related user information of, but ONLY OF THAT CURRENTLY LOGGED IN USER.

What I want is to ONLY delete the user information of ONLY THE SELECTED USER THAT IS SELECTED IN THE DROP DOWN.

Please excuse my ignorance I did spend a few hours trying to find the easiest solution on my own.

Here is the front ASPX Page:

```
<h3>Delete Users</h3>
    <p>
        <b>Select a User:</b>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="UserList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Page_Load"></asp:DropDownList>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="UserInfo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AspnetdbConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [UserName], [UserID] FROM [vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers] WHERE ([UserName] = @UserName)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="Username" ControlID="UserList" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            </SelectParameters>                
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="UserInfo" Height="50px">
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserId" HeaderText="UserId" SortExpression="UserId" />                                         
            </Fields>               
        </asp:DetailsView>
        <asp:Button id="DeleteButton" Text="Yes" OnClick="DeleteButton_OnClick" runat="server" />
    </p>
</div>
```

The Code Behind File is here:

```
 < using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.Security;

public partial class DeleteUsers : System.Web.UI.Page
{    
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DisplayUsersInGrid();
    }
}

private void DisplayUsersInGrid()
{
    UserList.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers();
    UserList.DataBind();
}

public void DeleteButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Membership.DeleteUser(User.Identity.Name);
    ActionStatus.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to delete the current logged in user.
You have to get the selected user id from dropdown and pass to DeleteUserFunction.

Replace Membership.DeleteUser(User.Identity.Name); with below

```
Membership.DeleteUser(UserList.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy, I was close! I appreciate it so much, I was just missing the selected value from the user list!